# Adding makers on graphs in Big Query Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio, data-anomalies

I have a time series graph in Looker studio and I would like to highlight some points on the graph (like using markers) to show anomalies (see below), however, I could not find any option in Looker Studio to highlight the points on the lines.

Any thoughts?
[image]